# How to deploy the pod which has same IP address with the host OS?

Tags: kubernetes

For instance, in a Kubernetes cluster environment created using kubeadm, there are management Pods with the same IP address as the host's IP address like below.

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide
NAME                              READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE
etcd-master1                      1/1       Running             13         49d       10.91.111.113   master1
kube-apiserver-master1            1/1       Running             18         49d       10.91.111.113   master1
kube-controller-manager-master1   1/1       Running             29         49d       10.91.111.113   master1
kube-proxy-6vrvb                  1/1       Running             13         81d       10.91.111.113   master1
kube-proxy-gsxcg                  1/1       Running             13         81d       10.91.111.114   worker1
kube-proxy-lcjvw                  1/1       NodeLost            1          64d       10.91.111.115   worker2
kube-scheduler-master1            1/1       Running             26         49d       10.91.111.113   master1
```

I would like to know how to write a yaml file for assigning the same IP address as the host to pod.

Answer (score 2):

on your podSpec add `hostNetwork: true`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot actually bind a same address for your pod, but you can user `HostNetwork` in your pod, which is actually will bind ports of your container to IP of your host machine one-to-one. That is actually is [Docker feature](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

Here is an example of a Pod yaml with that option enabled and Pod will bind port 80 on the host:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
    - name: myapp
      image: myapp:latest
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80`

But if you just want to access to your app in cluster using host's IP, it is not necessary to use that option. You can create `Service` with `NodePort` type, which will provide access to pods with your service. From official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-pods-to-the-cluster):

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    run: myapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    run: myapp`

In that case you will able to connect to any node on your cluster to port 80 and that request will be routed to your app.